# INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE when launch app on android emulator

Tags: android, react-native

When launching a React Native 0.64 app on android emulator with `npx react-native run-android`, it throws the error of installation of `app-debug.apk`

```
Unable to install C:\js\xyz_app4\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
```

this error complains about insufficient storage. There are plenty of disk space on the system and the disk size for the emulator is 4.6GB.  Here is the full error:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Unable to install C:\D\code\js\xyz_app4\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installRemotePackage(DeviceImpl.java:1224)
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackage(DeviceImpl.java:1050)
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackage(DeviceImpl.java:1026)
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackage(DeviceImpl.java:1015)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:130)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.install(InstallVariantTask.java:157)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.lambda$doTaskAction$1(InstallVariantTask.java:94)
        at com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceProvider.use(DeviceProvider.java:53)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.doTaskAction(InstallVariantTask.java:89)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:74)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:34)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:494)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:479)
```

In android studio, the rebuild of the project is success without error.

Comment: this is because the memory of emulator was full.try to delete something and try again

Comment: Hi `D_K`, the error disappears after wipe data on the emulator. thanks.